# Trabajar con tres arrays e insertar con PHP en base de datos MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, array

tengo el siguiente código:

```
foreach ( $_POST["num_cod"] as $num_cod) {
      echo $num_cod;
  }
  foreach ( $_POST["fec_cod"] as $fec_cod ) {
    echo $fec_cod;
  }
  foreach ( $_POST["nro_oper"] as $nro_oper ) {
    echo $nro_oper;
  }
```

En donde las variables: `$num_cod` , `$fec_cod` y `$nro_oper` , son arrays con `n` elementos cada uno en donde al primer elemento del primer array le corresponden el primer elemento del segundo y el primer elemento del tercer array. A cada array le corresponde una columna en una tabla. Lo que necesito es que se carguen en la tabla de mención cada elemento de cada array en su columna correspondiente y que se mantenga la relación entre los datos. He probado de varias formas pero no he obtenido los resultados esperados, esto es:

- Haciendo un `INSERT` por cada `foreach`: se insertan todas la variables pero no hay correlatividad de datos, es decir se carga los elementos del primer array en `n` filas, los del segundo array en las siguientes `n` filas, etc, llenando con ceros los otros campos.
- Anidando los `foreach` y un unico `INSERT` para las tres variables: se cargan `3.n` repeticiones de los datos.
- Haciendo un `INSERT` fuera de los `foreach` tampoco funciona.

Si alguien me puede ayudar puesto que la documentación de `php.net` no me ha ayudado demasiado. Con `array_merge()` podria hacer una matriz con los tres arrays pero no sabria como llevarlos a la tabla `mysql`. Siempre me complican los arrays. Desde ya muy agradecido por el tiempo que emplean los integrantes de este foro en ayudar a quienes sabemos menos.

Con:

```
echo $_POST['fec_cod'];
echo $_POST['nro_cod'];
echo $_POST['nro_oper'];
```

[image: con echo]

Con:

```
if ( !empty($_POST["nro_cod"]) && is_array($_POST["nro_cod"]) ) {
  echo "<ul>";
  foreach ( $_POST["nro_cod"] as $nro_cod ) {
          echo "<li>";
          echo "Código: ",$nro_cod;
          echo "</li>";
   }
   echo "</ul>";
```

[image: con foreach]

y funciona también con las otras dos variables.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[generar sql desde array](https://mimentevuela.wordpress.com/2016/02/16/generar-sql-desde-arrays-de-inputs-html5/#more-1121)

Encontré la respuesta. Gracias a @Alberto Siurob, quien fue el ÚNICO que se preocupó por aportar ayuda.

Answer (score 2):

Fácil, primero, estás seguro que cuando llega `$_POST` es un array? Por lo general se envia una cadena delimitada y le aplicas un `explode` para pasarlo a array. Ahora si los 3 datos tienen relación en su índice cómo dices, sólo nececitas ciclarlos pero con un `for`, no con `foreach`

```
$num_cod = $_POST['num_cod'];
$fec_cod = $_POST['fec_cod'];
$nro_oper = $_POST['nro_oper'];

for( $i = 0; $i < count( $num_cod ); $i++ ){
    $cod = $num_cod[$i];
    $fec = $fec_cod[$i];
    $nro = $nro_oper[$i];
    //Ya puedes hacer tu query, sería masomenos así
    $query = "INSERT INTO TABLA(CODIGO, FECHA, NUMERO) VALUES($cod, $fec, $nro)";
}
```

Como todos los índices tienen relación (En caso que tengamos un fuerte front-end) No tendrías ya problemas en ciclar y sacar los datos del mismo índice.

Saludos

Comment: Cuando listaba cada variable con el `foreach` tomaba cada variable como `array` (y asi estan declaradas)... Ahora me dice error y no carga los datos. Con el mismo formulario cargo datos a dos tablas mas y los datos de las otras dos tablas si se cargan.---

Comment: ¿Qué error te marca? Puedes poner que trae $_POST['num_cod'] por ejemplo

Comment: edité y amplié lo que me preguntaste.